# Systemd Script to backup folder - with deletion of old backups?

Tags: systemd, backup

This script creates a backup of one usb-drive over to another usb-drive, and excludes a temp file like '.Trash', and names the folder the date it was created:

```
'rsync -augAXPh --exclude '.Trash-*' /media/usb1/ /media/usb2/data-backup/$(date +%%Y-%%m-%%d)'
```

The next line is suppossed to search the directory ' /media/usb2/data-backup ' and delete any folders created 3 days or more ago:

```
'find /media/usb2/data-backup/*/* -mtime +3 -type d -exec rmdir -Rf {}'
Here's my complete 'data-backup.service' script.
```

And here is my entire 'data-backup.service' file, placed in /etc/systemd/system:

```
[Unit]
Description=Data backup

[Service]
Type=simple
Nice=19
StandardOutput=journal
IOSchedulingClass=best-effort
IOSchedulingPriority=5
ExecStart=sh -c 'rsync -augAXPh --exclude '.Trash-*' /media/usb1/ /media/usb2/data-backup/$(date +%%Y-%%m-%%d)' \;
    'find /media/usb2/data-backup/*/* -mtime +3 -type d -exec rmdir -Rf {}' \;

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

and just for the sake of helping someone else, here's my 'data-backup.timer' script, though there's no issue with it:

```
[Unit]
Description=Data backup timer
Requires=data-backup.service

[Timer]
OnCalendar=Mon..Sun 01:00
Unit=data-backup.service
Persistent=true

[Install]
WantedBy=timers.target
```

And if this issue gets easily solved, and anybody else wants to use it, I placed these two files in the directory, `'/etc/systemd/system/'` (for debian) then executed the command:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
```

and finally:

```
sudo systemctl start data-backup
```

I've created the systemd file(s) data-backup.service & data-backup.timer. The script executes correctly, and at the correct time I've designated in the data-backup.timer script. It creates a folder with the date of creation as it's name. It puts the backup data in the newly created folder. It just doesn't do the last step of deleting any directories older than 3 days. What am I missing? Thanks so much in advance!

Comment: I wouldn't put such complicated commands in the `ExecStart` of a service, it's hard to edit, debug and test (for example you have to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after each change). I would put the commands in a script file and test there. In `ExecStart` point to that script (file): `ExecStart=/path/to/script`.